Ubuntu 24.04 can't find my bluetooth keyboard but finds my Iphone
First time I pared the keyboard (HHKB pro hybrid) with my laptop (Lenovo Yoga 7 slim pro 14ACH5 running Ubuntu 24.04 kernel 6.8) it took a while before it showed up in the Bluetooth menu in settings.
Today I had to switch to windows 11 (I am running dual boot) to use a software for the new mouse I got. When I switched back to Ubuntu which I mainly use, my keyboard wouldn't connect. I figured I could just click "Forget device" and pair it again but now it never shows up under devices. I tried connecting a Bluetooth mouse (Logitech MX anywhere 3) I had around but that doesn't show up either. My IPhone shows up every time I test it and some random Realtek Bluetooth device which i don't own so it's probably my neighbor's.
I have tried using blueman, bluetoothctl, rfkill to block/unblock basically all I could find from other posts here or elsewhere. I went on windows, connected the keyboard, found the mac address and used in bluetoothctl pair (mac address)  but i got back device not available.I removed the devices from windows 11 Bluetooth devices, the keyboard can be pared with up to 4 devices and I tried with all 4 channels. Even deleted bluez and installed it again.
The Bluetooth device on my laptop works since my phone is detected and the phone detects it back. On windows 11 everything works as expected, keyboard is found immediately and pairs without any problems.
rfkill:
ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      ideapad_wlan      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth ideapad_bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth hci0              unblocked unblocked
 3 wlan      phy0              unblocked unblocked

[bluetooth]# show:
Controller F8:89:D2:7B:60:68 (public)
    Manufacturer: 0x0046 (70)
    Version: 0x0b (11)
    Name: Y7P
    Alias: Y7P
    Class: 0x007c010c (8126732)
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: no
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x000000b4 (180)
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0548
    Discovering: no
    Roles: central
    Roles: peripheral
Advertising Features:
    ActiveInstances: 0x00 (0)
    SupportedInstances: 0x08 (8)
    SupportedIncludes: tx-power
    SupportedIncludes: appearance
    SupportedIncludes: local-name
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: 1M
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: 2M
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: Coded



Is it possible that they can not be found because ther are connected to Windows? to test go back to windows disconnect at least the mouse an try to find it in Ubuntu.

It is common for Windows to hold the setting on hardware even after a reboot. So like @amar said go back to Windows and make sure it has not held the Bluetooth device.

I did that, still didn't work . Sorry forgot to mention it above, will edit

FIXED IT
What I did was:

Go into windows 11
Pair the keyboard (using first channel)
Removed it from the bluetooth devices (still in windows)
Restarted the laptop and went back to windows and waited a few seconds
Powered the laptop off waited a few seconds and powered it back on
Went into Ununtu and entered the keyboard into pairing mode in first channel
Using the terminal:
bluetoothctl then
power on
but got an error about bluez failing
Used rfkill block bluetooth then rfkill unblock bluetooth
Back to bluetoothctl this time power on worked and it found the keyboard
It was listed as "HHKB-Hybrid_1" and I used pair <its mac address> to pair
Typed the provided pin from the terminal on the keyboard I'm trying to pair and done


The waiting a few seconds is unnecessary.
